# How to search files which contain Chinese characters at terminal of Mac?

Tags: macos, shell, unicode, terminal, grep

I have a Vue.js project, there are some resource views containing Chinese characters, I want to find them all from the terminal.

I tried this, but there is no `-P` for my `grep`

```
grep -R -P '[\p{Han}]' resources
```

Comment: found a way to match certain character ``grep -R $'\u4FDD\u5B58' resources``

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found a solution with `pcregrep`, Chinese is in multiple unicode blocks, so this way is more simple.

```
pcregrep -r -n '[^\x00-\x7f]' resources
```

Comment: Your solution works fine on my system, though I wonder why `pcregrep '\p{Han}'` does not ... (surprisingly, my version of `grep` can handle it).

Comment: Oh, found it: you need to add the `-u` flag.

Answer (score 0):

Install https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep then

```
rg '\p{Script=Han}' resources
```